# Issue with my Facebook application

Tags: facebook

I uploaded an application on my Hosting server and integrated it with Facebook. All values including app id and app secret have been inserted correctly in the appinclude php file. When i open the app:

http://apps.facebook.com/feudalcastledefense/

It does not display anything, just the frame border. What could be the problem?

Comment: Check your app settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check you canvas url setting under apps section. If you canvas url is empty then it will not show up anything. Please check you setting and update in https://developers.facebook.com/apps
It should work.